# how to work around the icefaces ice:selectInputDate validation issue

Tags: jsf, icefaces

When using the IceFaces ice:selectInputDate a date selection always triggers the form validation.

So when a user selects a date all validation errors are shown. 
That's especially tedious when the date input is at the beginning of the form and all fields are empty. Then the user will get presented with all the "Value missing" error messages.

It's so frustating and really is a shame for such a widely-used framework like IceFaces.

Anybody got any hints how to handle this bug?

http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-4535

(immediate="true" does not help)

Thanks.

Comment: seems like it's a general problem with partialSubmit and validation: http://jsf-icefaces.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another and maybe better solution (or workaround) is described in this blog entry:
http://jsfbrickyard.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/a-better-alternative-for-the-icefaces-inputselectinputdate-control/

it describes how to use jquery UI datepicker instead of the ice:selectInputdate control.
comments welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the real problem is not the getting rid of the validation but that the validation for required="true" is missing completely after a partial submit is sent.

I resolved this here: http://jsfbrickyard.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/how-to-fix-the-requiredtrue-and-partial-submit-problem-in-icefaces/